# How can I find the exact value of the $\sum\limits_{i=1}^\infty\frac{x^i}{i}$?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, summation

I tried to solve with derivatives and integrals but this way I can only find that its closed form is $-\ln(1-x)$. How to find the exact value ?

Comment: $-\ln(1-x)$ *is* the exact value. What exactly are you looking for?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If $f(x)=\displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^\infty\frac{x^i}{i}$, then
$$f'(x)=\sum_{i=1}^\infty x^{i-1}=\frac{1}{1-x}$$for $|x|<1$. Notice that if $x=0$, then $f(0)=0$. This gives an initial value you can use to find a particular solution to the separable ODE above.